# i get this error in my browser console "typeError: $.ajax function not defined" in my codeigniter application

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

here is my search function from the controller

```js
public function search()
 {
  echo "content from database table" ;
  
 }
```

and here is my script tag which is loaded through a footer view of my codeIgniter application

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#state').change(function(){
  var stateIndex    = this.selectedIndex ; 
  var selectedState =
              this.options[stateIndex].value ; 
  var url = '<?php echo site_url('stores/pick') ?>' ;
  console.log(selectedState);
  $.ajax({
   dataType : 'html',
   type : 'post',
   data : { stateSelected : selectedState},
   url : url , 
   success : function(returnedData){
       alert(returnedData);
      }
  });
 });
 })
```

and after the onchange event on the select element is the of that alert to display I got this "typeError: $.ajax not defined" in my browser I have spent days searching internet regarding this but unble to locate an answer. Please will appreciate any useful help tips.
thanks in advance

Comment: Check if jQuery library is loaded before executing it's nethod (i.e. `.ajax({})`).

Comment: How is search() method related to question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change url variable like this.

```
var url = "<?php echo site_url('stores/pick') ?>";
```